# How to make a pointer between one node in RBtree to another tree?

Tags: java, red-black-tree

How can I make a pointer from one node in red-black tree to another node in a different red-black tree that contains all of the values for that same key from the first tree?
I mean, from every node in a red-black tree I'll have another red-black tree rooted from that node.

Thank you

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to write the code for the pointer.

Comment: Have a look at this http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/redblacktrees/